How to implement Push Notification in IOS platform with Azure Notification Hub in .NET MAUI .NET 8 version?
I have been in the process of converting my .NET MAUI project from .NET 6 to .NET 8. Currently, I am facing issues related to push notifications for the iOS platform when using the Plugin.Firebase package. As a result, I tried implementing push notifications using Azure Notification Hub, as suggested by a post I found online.
https://puresourcecode.com/dotnet/maui/maui-push-notifications-using-azure-notification-hub-for-ios/

Despite following all the necessary configurations mentioned in the post, I am still unable to receive push notifications. Additionally, I need assistance with testing the push notifications using Azure Notification Hub, as the documentation is not very clear.
I have completed the necessary setup by creating an Azure Notification Hub and providing the proper configuration for the backend, as per the documentation. However, I am still not receiving push notifications on my iOS device. Could you please provide guidance on how to resolve this issue and properly test push notifications using Azure Notification Hub?

First you need it install Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs package
Azure Notification in MAUI
It is working for me. You can follow the same steps and same code it will work for you also.
Best of luck.
